# Is there any way to see the names of a website's network requests with Google apps scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

So here's what I'm trying to do:

There's a website called Torah Anytime (https://www.torahanytime.com/) which publishes audio files (I guess you can call them podcasts, the website refers to them as shiurim, shiur being hebrew for song, or in this case, audio) on a daily basis. I would like to create a script that downloads the audio of specific speakers and then emails those files to me. The way I'm accomplishing this is with Google Apps Scripts. Torah Anytime allows you to follow specific speakers and to get email notifications when a speaker you're following puts out a new podcast. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
function main() {
  var emails = getemails();
  for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
      var email = emails[i].getMessages();
      if (email[0].getFrom() == "TorahAnytime Following <following@torahanytime.com>"){
      var title = getTitle(email);
      var shiurID = getShiurID(email);
      var downloadLink = "https://dl.torahanytime.com/audio/" + shiurID;
      var shiur = downloadShiur(downloadLink);
      shiur.setName(title);
      var emailSent = emailShiur(shiur);
      if (emailSent) {email[0].moveToTrash();
      Logger.log("Email moved to Trash");}
      }
  }
}

function getemails() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("TA Speeches");
      return label.getThreads();      
}

function getTitle(email) {     
  body = email[0].getPlainBody();
  var begIndex = body.indexOf("from") + 4;
  var endIndex = body.indexOf("on ");
  var title = body.substring(begIndex, endIndex).toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "-").replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "-");
  begIndex = body.indexOf("called ") + 7;
  endIndex = body.indexOf(" [");
  title += "-" + body.substring(begIndex, endIndex).toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "-").replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "-") + ".mp3";
  return title;
}

function getShiurID(email) {
body = email[0].getPlainBody();
var begIndex = body.indexOf("[") + 1;
var endIndex = body.indexOf("]");
var link = body.substring(begIndex, endIndex).replaceAll("?v", "?a");
console.log(link);
var mainLink = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link);
//here I somehow need to get the link being used to stream that particular audio file
}

function getIDName(email) {
body = email[0].getPlainBody();
var begIndex = body.indexOf("ID ") + 3;
var endIndex = body.indexOf(" and");
return body.substring(begIndex, endIndex);
}

function downloadShiur(downloadLink) {
  var audio = UrlFetchApp.fetch(downloadLink); 
  return audio.getBlob().getAs('audio/mp3');
}

function emailShiur(shiur) {
const maxFileSize = 26214400;
if (shiur.getBytes().length <= maxFileSize) {
MailApp.sendEmail("[Email addressed removed]", "TA Shiur (File)", "Enjoy!", {
     attachments: [shiur],
     name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
 });
 return true;
} else {
  MailApp.sendEmail("[Email addressed removed]", "TA Shiur (File)", "Error, File too large to email", {
     name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
 });
 return false;
}
}
```

My issue is that the URL to download the file is not in the HTML, so I don't know how to get to it  using GAS. If you use chrome's dev-tools, you can see the URL right there in the network tab [Example of output I see that I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj1av.png). Does anyone know of any way that I can get the information that I see in chrome's dev-tools network tab (the name's of the URLs being received) using GAS? Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, from `My issue is that the URL to download the file is not in the HTML, so I don't know how to get to it using GAS. If you use chrome's dev-tools, you can see the URL right there in the network tab.`, I cannot understand your current issue and your goal. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand them, can you provide the sample input value and sample output value you expect?

Comment: Input value: https://www.torahanytime.com/#/lectures?a=162956                                        Output Value: The names of the URLs that you see in the attached picture in my post

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing more information. I thought that the value you expect might be generated with Javascript. If my understanding is correct, unfortunately, I think that it is difficult to directly retrieve the value from the URL. I apologize for this.

Comment: Yeah, your browser's network monitor makes calls after a page loads. Perhaps you can see if any of the page's JS files get that URL.

Comment: They do make calls after the page loads, and I am able to see which URL they use. My problem is that each new podcast is streaming from a different URL, I want to be able to get that URL automatically via my script.